# How to combine two rows based on timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

So i know this is an odd way of doing it but ill try and explain.

I have the following table
trackingPoint{id, moduleId, lat, long, timestamp, first, last}

I now have the problem where points might arrive out of order. The php that handles the entry generates a trip record but it relies on order. I could adapt this script but im looking for a more efficient solution. I figure that if i do it all in a single query generated from the trackingPoints i eliminate some state, which cant be bad :D

The first tracking point in a trip is flagged with `first`=1
The last tracking point in a trip is flagged with `last`=1

So i need all rows where first=1, then i need to merge in the following row with last=1
To produce a row such as:
startTimestamp, endTimestamp, startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong, moduleId

Comment: And is there any relation between the starting and the ending record? For example moduleId or something? If not it's going to be impossible to connect them.. And are there always 2 or more points?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add a `TripID` column to your table, which you can trivially group or filter on. eg.

```
select * from trackingPoint where TripID = ?;
select tripID, min(ts), max(ts) from trackingPoint where TripID = ?;
```